# Host files on Tomcat possible?

Tags: tomcat

I have a Tomcat 6.0.24 server running. I'm using to run some JSP pages. Would it be possible to host files on it? E.g. If I type in http://localhost:8080/Sample.avi I would download Sample.avi? Probably there are better servers I guess for this task, but I'd like to stick to Tomcat since I don't wish to install another server. Is it possible?

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible: simply add a <Context> in the server.xml file to point to the directory containing you files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. A quick google suggests you need a `StaticInterceptor`

What you call "files" is usually called "static content" in web terms: a fixed resource at a specific URI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ,

1. Place the static files that you want to host in a folder.
2. Launch IntelliJ -> Select Tomcat -> Edit Configuration -> Deployment -> + -> External Source -> Select the above folder and set the application context (For e.g. static)
3. You can access the files with http://localhost:// (For e.g.
   http://localhost:8080/static/static_image.png)

[IntelliJ setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CurKq.png)